# How to set current location as initialPosition in PlacePicker with GoogleMaps - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

How do i change **initialPosition** in **PickerPlace** to current position?
I would like the user's location to be displayed at the start

I'm currently using **geolocator**, **google_maps_flutter**

I would have to give the currentPosition in initialPosition but I don't know how
add current location to initial.

Is there any other way to do it?
Every possible help is very much appreciated.

```
 class SosScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 const SosScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static final kInitialPosition = LatLng(50.04119, 18.4646689);

 @override
 _SosScreenState createState() => _SosScreenState();

 static Route route() {
   return MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (_) => SosScreen());
}
}

 class _SosScreenState extends State<SosScreen> {
 PickResult? selectedPlace;


@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: _mapAlert(context),
);
}


String _locationMessage = '';

 void getCurrentLocation() async {
final position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
print(position);

 setState(() {
  _locationMessage = "${position.latitude},${position.longitude}";
} );
}


 Widget _mapAlert(BuildContext context) {
return Center(
    child: Container(
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.orangeAccent, width: 2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: PlacePicker(
          apiKey: '',
          initialPosition: SosScreen.kInitialPosition,
          useCurrentLocation: true,
          selectInitialPosition: true,
          usePlaceDetailSearch: true,
          onPlacePicked: (result) {
            selectedPlace = result;
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            setState(() {});
          },
          forceSearchOnZoomChanged: true,
          pinBuilder: (context, state) {
            if (state == PinState.Idle) {
              return Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.orange);

              //   Image(
              //   image: AssetImage(
              //     'assets/images/orange_small_logo.png',
              //   ),
              //   height: 50,
              //   width: 20,
              // );
            } else {
              return Icon(
                Icons.favorite_border,
                color: Colors.orange,
              );
            }
          },
        )));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static final kInitialPosition = LatLng(50.04119, 18.4646689);
//Remove static keyword.

     void getCurrentLocation() async {
           position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
          print(position);

          setState(() {
            _lofinalcationMessage = "${position.latitude},${position.longitude}";
            SosScreen.kInitialPosition = position;
          } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future getCurrentLocation() async {

    final position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

      final userLocation = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      print(userLocation);
      return userLocation;
  }
```